How to make a c exe global in Ubuntu
I have a file called fsm.c and with the command gcc fsm.c -o fsm I have a new file called fsm. I want to execute the particular file wherever I am while using the terminal.
I tried to move it in the /usr/local/gcc directory but gcc crashed and I had to reinstall it.

I tried to move it in the /usr/local/gcc directory What? Why?

Did you try simply: ./fsm from the current directory? Please clarify the exact problem you’re facing. There is not a question here.

I'm not a C dev, but I don't think there's anything C-specific about this, so look at this question on Ask Ubuntu: When installing user applications, where do "best practices" suggest they be located? Or you can read the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS) yourself, e.g. /usr/local

Both C and GCC are irellavent when it comes to how an executable binary is executed by the operating system.  It is also not really about software development, it is about OS behaviour.  Suggest superuser.com.
